# Suppress "Error during loading" message in standalone Jasmine 3.1 browser report

Tags: jasmine

When using 3.1 of standalone Jasmine I see the message `Error during loading: Script error.` for each of my scripts as they load.

When I was using standalone version 2.9.1 I would see the errors in the console but not blasted on the page.

These errors are irrelevant as I mock the missing pieces that are the cause of the errors when I run my tests.

Is there any way to suppress these from showing in the standalone HTML page report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was actually able to resolve it.

If I move my source files above the jasmine files in the SpecRunner.html file it does not display the errors in the report but it still runs my tests successfully.